# blurriness issue in custom scrollbar

Tags: css, reactjs, scrollbar, styled-components

I have a custom scrollbar that I created using styled components. However, when the scrollbar appears, the content within it experiences some blurriness issues. Here is my styled container for the custom scrollbar:

```
const Container = styled.aside`
  .scrollbar-container {
    overflow-y: scroll;
    overflow-x: hidden;

    ::-webkit-scrollbar {
      width: 8px;
      background-color: #ececec;
    }

    ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
      border-radius: 6px;
      background-color: #a5a5a5;
    }
  }
`;
```

and here is where is used it :

```
{type === INDICATOR_TIME_TYPE.TYPE_QUALITY ? (
  <Container>
    <div
      className={`grid grid-cols-2 grid-rows-${data?.indicatorValues.length} gap-2 bg-slate-100 rounded px-3 py-5 mt-5 text-xs text-center h-[6rem] scrollbar-container`}
    >
      <IndicatorViewTypeQuality data={data?.indicatorValues} />
    </div>
  </Container>
) : null}
```

anu suggestion for this issue?